# Add Class to Button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to add a class to a button for a small animation after a click on the button. At the moment I had the problem, that I receive this information:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

I can not add a new class, can someone help me?

```js
function animateClick(ID) {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById(ID);
  var todo = this;
  todo.classList.add("rotate");
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      elmnt.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }, 500
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-icons-img">
  <button onclick="animateClick('welcome')">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf..." />
    <span class="tooltiptext1">
     Welcome Text
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am guessing `todo` is not what you think it is. `console.log(this)` Should it be `elmnt`?

Comment: `this` is `window`. Do not use `onclick` attributes. Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: There is no element with an id of "welcome" in the code you've shared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're able to use `addEventListener` instead `onclick`, because separate logic it's a good practice.
You can explicitly indicate your button by sending `this` as an argument.

```js
function animateClick(ID, btn) {
var elmnt = document.getElementById(ID);
var todo = btn;
todo.classList.add("rotate");
setTimeout(
    function() {
        elmnt.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
    }, 500
);}
```

```html
<div class="nav-icons-img">
 <button onclick="animateClick('welcome', this)">
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf..." />
    <span class="tooltiptext1">
     Welcome Text
    </span>
   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As many have said, todo (`this`) is not what you thought it was. `this` in a function in the DOM, unless inside an [event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp), refers to the window object. You may have thought that it meant the element. This is because the computer does not know that you are going to call the function in an element's onclick attribute. There are two ways to tackle this.

1. You could pass in `this` as an argument of a second parameter, `todo`, like so

Here is code from [this](https://jsfiddle.net/404_Error/uhj17d4b/) fiddle.

```
window.animateClick = function(ID, todo) {
console.log(todo);
var elmnt = document.getElementById(ID);
todo.classList.add("rotate");
setTimeout(function() {
  elmnt.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }, 500);
}
```

2. Or, you could create an [event listener method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) instead of using the `onclick` attribute

Follow this format:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var todo = this;
    ....
});
```

Lastly, you should be able to add a new class, but in the code you have given us, there is no element with an id of welcome so it is null add an element with an id of welcome and it will work.